# Make Python3 default without breaking yum in RHEL7

Tags: rhel, python, yum, python3, cloud-init

> **What specific syntax needs to be changed or added to the below in order for commands calling `python` in a RHEL7 VM to be interpreted using Python3 WITHOUT breaking programs like `yum` that require Python2?**

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**

---

Our first attempt was to add the following 2 lines to the very end of the `cloud-init` startup script which instantiates the VM:

```
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

**ERROR THAT RESULTED:**

---

The problem is that adding the above two lines to the end of the `cloud-init` startup script causes `yum` commands to break when `yum` is called afterwards as follows:

```
$ sudo yum update -y
  File "/bin/yum", line 30
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$
```

**TOGGLING THE ERROR:**

---

We can turn off the error by removing the above 2 lines from the `cloud-init` startup script and re-instantiating a new replacement VM.  This isolates the source of the problem, but still we have the problem of how to default `python` to Python3 without breaking apps like `yum`.

Comment: You are not able to replace the default Python on RHEL 7 based machines, as all system provided Python scripts (such as `yum`) depend on the default Python version.  If your users need to use Python3 instead of the default Python, then Python3 should be set as preferred in the user's profile and you would not make those changes for the `root` user.  You could also use RHEL 8, which lets you set which version of Python you want as default.

Comment: The question is why you need to do this?

Comment: If this is something that you wrote or can alter, then why not just edit it to call `python3` instead of `python`? As previously stated, you can't replace the default Python in RHEL 7. Doing so causes the problems that you are seeing.

Comment: @NasirRiley  Another way of considering this question is to ask if `yum` can be configured to call `python2` explicitly.  ...  There are complications with any approach to the current problem.  Approaching the problem from the direction mentioned here would prevent complications resulting from approaching the problem from other directions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack you can use in an emergency:

```
sed -i 1s/python/python2/ /bin/yum
```

I wouldn't use it as a solution - it creates inconsistency and also only fixes `yum`.  There may well be other system or other tools that depend on pythin2.  Just my 0.02.